# Do not show root folder in the VSCode sidebar explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my new laptop VSCode started to behave differently in comparison to my old laptop.

If i add only one folder to the workspace, I want the folder itself not to appear, only it's contents.

In the screenshot below, i'd want the workspace to directly have all the contents of `iac-vcs` folder, not nested them under the `iav-vcs`, as it is currently. It seems to me that's how my old VSCode setup behaved, can't replicate it again.

[image: VSCode screen]

My workspace config looks as follows:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "<absolut-path-to-added-folder>/iac-vcs/"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
    }
}
```

And my user settings are as follows:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "workbench.editor.untitled.hint": "hidden",
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "explorer.compactFolders": false,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "files.autoSaveDelay": 50,
    "[python]": {
        "editor.rulers": [80]
    },
    "search.useReplacePreview": false,
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
}
```

How do I tell VSCode to get do not show `iac-vcs` in the sidebar if there is only single folder added to a workspace?

It is also important to note that if I save new workspace, I do get the expected results:
[image]

But upon closing the window and loading the workspace again, it gets to the state I initially described.

Many thanks!

Comment: Update - this was marked as bug by VSCode team: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/143514 .

Answer (score 1):

For a [single-folder workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces#_singlefolder-workspaces) just open the folder using `File -> Open Folder...`, then you will have the folder's contents in the explorer.

To ignore the `.vscode` folder, add the following to your workspace settings:

```json
"files.exclude": {
    ".vscode": true,
}
```

For a more convenient GUI-based way you might use the [Explorer Exclude](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RedVanWorkshop.explorer-exclude-vscode-extension) extension.

Comment: Thanks for comment! The very fact that the state changes after saving and reopening a workspace seems to be a bug https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/143514. And you need workspace for settings storage that are specific for the project but do not fit into common .vscode/settings.json.

Comment: Interesting observation. However, opening the folder results in a workspace as well (see [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces#_how-do-i-open-a-vs-code-workspace)). Workspace settings go into `<folder>/.vscode/settings.json` then (this is the file opened when running the `Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)` command).
The `File -> Add Folder To Workspace` menu item is needed ONLY if you want to add ANOTHER folder to your existing workspace, resulting in a [multi-root workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces#_multiroot-workspaces).